# Calibre - Kindle paperwhite won't show .epub book cover

Tags: calibre

I set the cover through Calibre and saved the book locally. Cover showed nicely for Apple Books, but when I sent it to my kindle paperwhite it just doesn't show.

I am not able to send it through calibre. I am getting a `ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused')` so the only way is to send it through my mail.

Answer (score 0):

The EPUB format spec supports PNG and JPG formats I believe. What format is the cover image in? The EPUB spec is clear on what it supports but not all readers support the full spec. Check the details for what image types the Paperwhite supports.

As such the Kindle Paperwhite should also fully support PNG and JPG images, but I wouldn't bet money on it.

Which image editor last touched and saved the cover image? Can you try to use another image editor, resave the image, and remake your EPUB?

Comment: Cover is in PNG format which paperwhite supports. Cover was done in canva and downloaded as PNG.

Which editor would you recommend to try?

Comment: When making EPUB cover images I never had a problem with using Irfanview, it's free. https://irfanview.com Looks like Irfanview is Windows only. For other OSs, try GIMP, also free. @LukasLukeStateczny

Comment: IrfanView also runs *very* well on Linux in wine, and is my preferred general-purpose editor in that OS. That said, Kindle was first a closed ecosystem, designed around MOBI, so try exporting in that format from Calibre.

Answer (score 0):

Since Amazon started supporting EPUB format files in the Send to Kindle service, including covers seems to have stopped working.

There was a point where including the Amazon identifier in the Ids metadata (which you can automatically populate through the Download metadata function) helped, but I have not had a consistent experience with this.